# Keras, how does SGD learning rate decay work?

Tags: neural-networks, python

If you look at the documentation http://keras.io/optimizers/ there is a parameter in the SGD for decay.  I know this reduces the learning rate over time.  However, I can not figure out how it works exactly.  Is it a value which is multiplied by the learning rate such as `lr = lr * (1 - decay)`  is it exponential?  Also how can I see what learning rate my model is using?  When I print `model.optimizer.lr.get_value()` after running a fit over a few epochs it gives back the original learning rate even though I set the decay.

Also do I have to set nesterov=True to use momentum or are there just two different types of momentum I can use.  For instance is there a point to doing this `sgd = SGD(lr = 0.1, decay = 1e-6, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = False)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The documentation that you're referring to includes a reference to the Python source (just click on the `[Source]` link in the appropriate place), that can be used to answer your questions. Here's the most relevant line, showing how `decay` modifies the learning rate:

```
lr = self.lr * (1. / (1. + self.decay * self.iterations))
```

The `nesterov` option does not have to be set to True for momentum to be used; it results in momentum being used in a different way, as again can be seen from the source:

```
v = self.momentum * m - lr * g  # velocity

if self.nesterov:
    new_p = p + self.momentum * v - lr * g
else:
    new_p = p + v
```

Comment: and `self.iterations` refers to the number of individual SGD steps, not the number of epochs, rigt?